# парсер выдает ироглифы вместо русских букв

Tags: python, парсер, utf-8

сделал парсер на библиотеке (from bs4 import BeautifulSoup)
но вместо русских букв парсер выдает ироглифы

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import fake_useragent
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random




HOST = "https://directlot.ru"
URL1 = "https://directlot.ru/lot.php?id=801626"
HEADERS2 = {'User_Agent': user}
response1 = requests.get(URL1,  headers = HEADERS2, ).text
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1, 'html.parser')
block = soup1.find('div', class_ = 'goodsInOpisanie').get_text(strip = True),


print (block)
```

как я понял из гугла (хорошая вещ кста) нужна кодировка utf-8 но как ей пользоваться я непонял

> > > вот вывод
> > > [image: вот вывод]

Comment: `soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.encode('ISO-8859-1'), 'html.parser')`

Comment: СПС помогло :))

Comment: @Andy Pavlov не нужно кодировать обратно, нужно просто брать `.content` вместо `.text`: `response1 = requests.get(URL1,  headers = HEADERS2).content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import fake_useragent
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random




HOST = "https://directlot.ru"
URL1 = "https://directlot.ru/lot.php?id=801626"
HEADERS2 = {'User_Agent': user}
response1 = requests.get(URL1,  headers = HEADERS2, ).text
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.encode('ISO-8859-1'), 'html.parser')
block = soup1.find('div', class_ = 'goodsInOpisanie').get_text(strip = True),


print (block)
```

Вот рабочий код